# java.sql.SQLException con conexion a la base de datos fuera de rango(3 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, sql-server, java-swing, javafx

he estado programando una pequeña interfaz para un administrador(todo es de prueba es de ejercicio) y al momento de iniciar sesión arroja:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

y en el código he implementado lo siguiente:

```
public class LoginAdmin extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

 
 String url = "";
String user = "";
String pass = "";
Administrador admin;

public LoginAdmin() {
    initComponents();
}

public Administrador getAdmin() {
    return admin;
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String contra = new String(txt_pass.getPassword());
    int flagCorreo = 0,flagContra = 0,flagVeri = 0;
    
    try {
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("select * from administradores where correo = ?");
        pst.setString(3, txt_correo.getText().trim());
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        
        while(rs.next()){
            
            if(txt_correo.getText().trim().equals(rs.getString("correo"))){
                flagCorreo = 1;
                if(contra.equals(rs.getString("contraseña"))){
                    flagContra = 0;
                }
                if(txt_veri.getText().trim().equals(rs.getString("verificador"))){
                    flagVeri = 1;
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        if (flagCorreo == 1 && flagContra == 1 && flagVeri == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido "+rs.getString("nombre")+"!");
            seleccionarAdmin(rs.getString("correo"),rs.getString("nombre"),contra,Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id")),Integer.parseInt(txt_veri.getText().trim()),Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("edad")));
            txt_correo.setText("");
            txt_pass.setText("");
            txt_veri.setText("");
            dispose();
        }else{
            if(flagCorreo == 1 && flagContra == 0 && flagVeri == 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contraseña Incorrecta.");
                txt_veri.setText("");
                txt_pass.setText("");
            }else{
                if (flagCorreo == 1 && flagContra == 1 && flagVeri == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID de trabajo erronea.");
                    txt_veri.setText("");
                    txt_pass.setText("");
                }else{
                    if (flagCorreo == 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Administrador NO existe, por favor registrarlo.");
                        txt_correo.setText("");
                        txt_pass.setText("");
                        txt_veri.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO HAY CONEXION A LA BD");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
}                                        


private void seleccionarAdmin(String correo,String nombre,String contra,int id,int idTrabajador,int edad){
    admin = new Administrador(correo,nombre,contra,id,idTrabajador,edad);
}
```

tengo un administrador que es para poder almacenarlo y enviarlo a otras clases y poder saber quien es el "administrador" que ha hecho las ultimas modificaciones.

lo que percibo es que puede ser un error al momento de generar el `PreparedStatement`, (los datos de la tabla son una id[int],nombre[varchar],correo[varchar],contraseña[varchar],edad[int],verificador[int] (el verificador es una serial que se le otorgara al administrador)  )

Comment: Pues si solo vas a pasar un parametro debería ser:  `pst.setString(1, txt_correo.getText().trim());`

Comment: gracias, era eso, pero ahora tendré que buscar porque arroja 
`java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set`

Comment: Puedes especificar en que linea? Ademas puedes indicar cuantos registros devuelve el query? Pregunto eso porque veo que usas rs.get.... fuera del ciclo while

Comment: Tienes que efectuar la lectura de resultados dentro del `while`, cuando el código salga de ese bloque significa que no habrá más registros en `rs`, el error que estás teniendo es por ese motivo, pues aquí: `if (flagCorreo == 1 && flagContra == 1 && flagVeri == 1) {` el `rs` habrá sido recorrido totalmente y no podrás acceder a valores como `rs.getString("nombre")`  Es cuestión de organizar, limpiar, simplificar un poquito el código. Está un poco "spaghetado" y eso provoca errores de este tipo. Si necesitas algún dato que sea parte de `rs` fuera de la lectura, tendrás que guardarlo en variables